# java fx problems with fonts rendering after moving project from java 8.11 to 8.21 and higher

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Actually problems start from build 8.21 (there was global changes), so how to fix problems with fonts and styles, maybe someone had this problem too...

Comment: Try setting the `prism.order` system property to `j2d`, either on the command line or in code before launching your application, to disable OpenGL rendering.

Comment: I think the `prism.order` setting also changed to `sw` instead of `j2d`, though `j2d` may still work.

Comment: What are the problems and how can they be replicated by somebody else?

Comment: Problems with fonts in all controls: text is blurred in some places, behind one letter in text could be pink or yellow spot... all controls after transfer works good, only problems with fonts.